# Handling duplicate data in foreign key while performing aggregation

Tags: oracle, duplicates

I am learning Oracle performance tuning, and not very good with tuning queries. Any help for below question would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

I have two tables:

**Employee**:

```
empno   deptno   sal   
1       10       800
1       20       800 ( Employee 1 works in multiple departments)
2       10       1000
3       30       1200
```

**Department**:

```
Department_id  department_name  
10                Finance
20                HR
30                MANAGER
```

Now I want to find total salaries paid in each department. I have written below query which is giving me result needed but I am not sure if this query will perform better in table where we may have millions of records and huge duplication.

```
With t as
(
   select 
       empno, department_id, sal  
   from 
       emp e  
   join 
       departments d on e.deptno = d.department_id
   order by 
       empno),
t1 as
(
    select 
        empno, max(sal)/count(1) salary 
    from 
        t
    group by 
        empno)
select 
    department_id, sum(salary) 
from 
    t 
join
    t1 on t.empno = t1.empno
group by 
    department_id;
```

Query took .059 seconds for 15 records in employee with no Unique Key and PK used.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want the total salary by department, then it's as simple as:

```
select deptno, sum(sal)
from employee
group by deptno
```

Comment: This will give wrong result as even if employee 1 is working for 2 departments simultaneously but he is being paid only 800 and not 800 each by both departments.

Comment: @user7571721. OK. How do you determine which departments pays the salary for a given employee 1. For example, is employee 1 paid by department 10 or 20?

Comment: Say both pay half or only 10 pays..Could you please help me with both the queries.  I could only figure out one query ...not sure how to write query when only 10 pays.

Comment: @user7571721 Well the question still remains; what is the algorithm that determines that 10 pays?

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to select anything from `department`, so it is not clear why you need a join.

To allocate salary across departments, when an employee is in more than one department, you can use the analytic function `count()` in a subquery. Something like:

```
with
     employee ( empno, deptno, sal ) as ( 
       select 1, 10,  800 from dual union all
       select 1, 20,  800 from dual union all
       select 2, 10, 1000 from dual union all
       select 3, 30, 1200 from dual
     ),
     prep ( empno, deptno, sal, dept_cnt ) as (
       select empno, deptno, sal, count(*) over (partition by empno)
       from   employee
     )
select   deptno, sum(sal/dept_cnt) as total_sal
from     prep
group by deptno
order by deptno 
;

DEPTNO  TOTAL_SAL
------ ----------
    10       1400
    20        400
    30       1200
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for response, As I want to calculate department wise monthly expense, What if some department does not have any employee right now? That time we need to join it with department table. Correct me if I am wrong?